# How to configure multiple intranet website on server 2003?

Tags: iis, web, intranet

I have two intranet website but they are as folders under default website so I would access as //server-internal/websitedirectory1/ adn //server-internal/websitedirectory2. Users don't like this. They want to access with some meaningful name like website1.intranet.com and website2.intranet.com. How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This should be asked on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1):

You will have a problem if these two "sites" share session information. Test this by setting up two virtual folders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add multiple Web Sites in IIS and set them to respond to different Host headers (in Properties)

You'll also need to set up DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the quikc reply. ok. I have set up the host headers as website1.intranet.com and website2.intranet2 for two different websites with the same ip address but how do i setup dns? the ip address of the server is one that i am suppose to set up for website? or can i assign any random ip for both website?

Comment: Both domain names must resolve to the IP address of your server. (Otherwise, the website would be unreachable)

Comment: ok thanks. so how do i setup up dns now? and do i need to restart iis in order to make this change effective?